# If $ab+bc+ca\ge1$, prove that $\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}\ge\frac{\sqrt{3}}{abc}$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, muirhead-inequality

The following problem is from CHKMO 2018 Problem 1:

> If $ab+bc+ca\ge1$, prove that $$\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}\ge\frac{\sqrt{3}}{abc}$$

I tried to use Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, by try multiplying different things, such as $1^2+1^2+1^2$, $(abc)^2+(abc)^2+(abc)^2$. But I still can’t solve it. Can someone help me?

Comment: the reference seems to be wrong, here is the CHKMO 2018 problems: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c571562_2018_chkmo.

Comment: There are many similar questions, for [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2133854/1618).

Comment: This is equivalent to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702891/a-b-c-are-positive-real-numbers-such-that-abc-ge-abc-prove-that-a2b2?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $x=\dfrac{1}{a}, y=\dfrac{1}{b}, z=\dfrac{1}{c}$. It is easy to get
$$x^2+y^2+z^2\ge xy+yz+zx$$ which is $$\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2}+\dfrac{1}{c^2}\ge\dfrac{1}{ab}+\dfrac{1}{bc}+\dfrac{1}{ca}=\dfrac{a+b+c}{abc}$$
We try to prove $a+b+c\ge\sqrt{3}$. As $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca\ge1$,
$$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca\ge3\\ a+b+c\ge\sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

Because for positive variables by Muirhead we obtain: $$\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2\geq\sum_{cyc}a^2bc\geq abc\sqrt{3(ab+ac+bc)}\geq\sqrt3abc$$

Answer (score 2):

AM-GM leads to 
\begin{align*}
     \frac{a^2b^2}{c^2}+\frac{b^2c^2}{a^2}&\geqslant 2\sqrt{\frac{a^2b^2}{c^2}\cdot \frac{b^2c^2}{a^2}}=2b^2
\end{align*}

Similarly

\begin{align*}
     \frac{a^2b^2}{c^2}+\frac{b^2c^2}{a^2}\geqslant 2b^2\qquad \frac{b^2c^2}{a^2}+\frac{c^2a^2}{b^2}&\geqslant 2c^2\qquad \frac{c^2a^2}{b^2}+\frac{a^2b^2}{c^2}\geqslant 2a^2\\
     \\
     \therefore \frac{a^2b^2}{c^2}+\frac{b^2c^2}{a^2}+\frac{c^2a^2}{b^2}&\geqslant a^2+b^2+c^2
\end{align*}

Hence
\begin{align*}
    \frac{a^2b^2}{c^2}+\frac{b^2c^2}{a^2}+\frac{c^2a^2}{b^2}+2a^2+2b^2+2c^2&\geqslant 3a^2+3b^2+3c^2\\
    \iff \left(\frac{ab}{c}+\frac{bc}{a}+\frac{ca}{b}\right)^2&\geqslant 3a^2+3b^2+3c^2\tag{1}
\end{align*}

And since $a^2+b^2+c^2\geqslant ab+bc+ac$, we obtain $$\left(\frac{ab}{c}+\frac{bc}{a}+\frac{ca}{b}\right)^2\geqslant 3\cdot(ab+bc+ac)\geqslant3$$ Can you finish now?

Answer (score 0):

Just as what was done in [Post 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3465571/if-abbcca-ge1-prove-that-frac1a2-frac1b2-frac1c2-ge-frac/3465593#3465593), we can substitute;
$$a=\frac{1}{x}$$
$$b=\frac{1}{y}$$
$$c=\frac{1}{z}.$$

Then, we have that;
\begin{align*}
& \text{ } \text{ } \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ } ab+bc+ca \geq 1\\
&\implies \frac{1}{xy}+\frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{zx}\geq 1\\
&\implies \frac{xyz}{xy}+\frac{xyz}{yz}+\frac{xyz}{zx}\geq xyz\\
&\implies x+y+z\geq xyz.\hspace{7.7cm} \rightarrow 1
\end{align*}

We can now proceed as in this link [Linked Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/702933/881969)

We know by the QM-AM inequality that;
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{3}}
&\geq \left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right)^2\\
&\geq \left(\frac{xyz}{3}\right)^2.\hspace{2cm} \left(\text{Note that }x+y+z\geq xyz\right)\\
\end{align*}

Squaring both sides and multiplying by 3 gives;
$$x^2+y^2+z^2\geq \frac{x^2y^2z^2}{3}$$

\begin{align*}
\implies\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^\frac{1}{4}
&\geq \left(\frac{x^2y^2z^2}{3}\right)^\frac{1}{4}\\
&\geq \frac{\sqrt{xyz}}{3^\frac{1}{4}}.\hspace{6cm} \rightarrow 2\\
\end{align*}

By AM-GM, we know that;

$$\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{3}\geq \sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}$$
$$\implies x^2+y^2+z^2\geq 3\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}$$
$$\implies \left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^3\geq 3^3\left(x^2y^2z^2\right)$$
\begin{align*}
&\implies \left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^\frac{3}{4}\geq 3^\frac{3}{4}\sqrt[4]{x^2y^2z^2}\\
&\implies \left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^\frac{3}{4}\geq 3^\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{xyz}.\hspace{5.05cm} \rightarrow 3
\end{align*}

We can now multiply Inequality 2 and 3 to have;

\begin{align*}
x^2+y^2+z^2
&=\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^\frac{1}{4}\times \left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^\frac{3}{4}\\
&\geq \frac{\sqrt{xyz}}{3^\frac{1}{4}}\times 3^\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{xyz}\\
&\geq xyz\sqrt{3}.
\end{align*}

Substituting back the original variables yields the desired result;
$$\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}\geq\sqrt{3}\frac{1}{abc}$$
$$\implies\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}\geq\frac{\sqrt{3}}{abc}.$$